# How to replace backward slash with forward in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace forward slash with backward with below code but the result is not as expected, What's the expected second parameter for `replace` in this case?

```js
var path = 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe';
path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
console.log(path)
```

*result*:

> "C:UsersabcAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython37python.exe"

Comment: As @anubhava explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56809606/4265352) the problem is not in the `regex` but in the input string. Read about [strings in the JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is fine but variable declaration needs double backslash because single backslash is interpreted as escape character:

```js
var path = 'C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe';
path = path.replace(/\\/g, "/");

console.log(path);
//=> C:/Users/abc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
```

---

If you want to avoid using `\\` in assignment then you can use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

```
var path = String.raw`C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`;
```

Comment: Is there any way to add those backslashes programmatically in the operand string?

Comment: Once you have `path = 'C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe';` then all traces of ``\`` are gone. Try to use `console.log` after that assignment and you will see same behavior.

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use `String.raw` to avoid double ``\\``

Comment: Excellent advice about `String.raw()`!

Comment: that's great @anubhava thanks

Answer (score -4):

path.replace(/\134/g,"/");

As a regular expression. \134 is the octal representation of a backslash

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Comment: #include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
 char str[] = "\134"; 
 printf("%s", str); 
 return 0; 
} For me it works, why shouldn't it solve the problem?

Comment: This user is using javascript (see tag), which considers \ as an escape character. In C++ this is not the case. Your solution would work on your example in C/C++, but not JS.